# How to use custom directive in angularJs ng-disabled?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-disabled

I have following directive defined.

```
limsApp.directive('isPermissionValid', ['Service', function(Service) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            isPermissionValid: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
           
            if (Service.hasPermissionFor(scope.isPermissionValid)) {
               elem[0].disabled = false;
            } else {
               elem[0].disabled = true;
            }
            
        }
    }
}]);
```

here is html code

```
<input is-permission-valid="['Create/Update']" type="text" id="label" ng-model="test.name">
```

This text field is disabled based on condition.

```
<button is-permission-valid="['Create/Update']" type="button" ng-click="save()" 
ng-disabled="!test.name" >Save</button>
```

but when there is already ng-disabled then this is not working. above button is always enabled.
When i remove ng-disabled from above button then it is working fine when directive gives true.
so how to disable text field or button when there is already ng-disabled in that element.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to create an `is-permission-valid` directive in your scenario, you can directly combine the logic and pass it to ng-disabled attribute, something like:

```
ng-disabled="!test.name || !isPermissionValid"
```

Or maybe 1 variable to control is enough:

HTML:

```
ng-disabled="shouldDisableButton"
```

Controller:

```
$scope.shouldDisableButton = !test.name || !isPermissionValid
```